# xDebug Remote-Debugging Session does not start

Tags: php, debugging, phpstorm, xdebug, firewall

I have the following problem.
I want to use xDebug for Debugging in PHPStorm.
I want to do this via Remote-Debugging.
But the xDebug-Session does not trigger.

I installed the browser xDebug-Helper-Plugin and I selected PHP-Storm. I activated the plugin for my web-application I want to debug (the address of my application I want to debug is "gm01.powty.com/acc3_dev/" in my case).

In PHPStorm I configured a Server like this:
[picture of Server configuration in PHPStorm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eq966.png)

Then I activated the Listener in PHPStorm (The green phone).

I checked my IP on my Work-PC with "ipconfig" for configuration on the Server later (the ip was 10.50.21.224 in my case).

I also executed "netstat -a" to check if the state of "0.0.0.0:9000" was in the "Listening"-state.

Then I configured my Apache-Server of course.
I downloaded the correct xdebug.dll by using my phpinfo() of my Server.
I added the following lines to the php.ini on my Server: [php.ini on Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBJCp.png)

Then I restarted my server to make my configuration active.
I also checked it via phpinfo().

By when I enter the address of my Webapplication in the Browser, the debug-Session does not start. I do not know why, because my configuration seems correct.

I also added the "xdebug.remote_log"-line to my php.ini later.
When I enter the address of my webapplication in the browser the following is added to the log-file:

```
Log opened at 2017-07-25 12:41:33
I: Connecting to configured address/port: 10.50.21.224:9000.
E: Time-out connecting to client. :-(
Log closed at 2017-07-25 12:41:33
```

What could be the reason of the problem. Could it be a firewall-problem? What could prevent the debug-session from starting?

Comment: lets see your php.ini xdebug settings from the server

Comment: My Work-PC uses Trend-Micro OfficeScan. Is there a possibility the anti-varis-software can block my connection?

Comment: @delboy1978uk
[XDebug]

zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.5.4-5.6-vc11.dll"

xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_host = 10.50.21.224
xdebug.remote_log = "C:\xampp\xdebugtmp\xdebug.log"
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1

Comment: more than likely. Try setting up a remote debug tunnel in puTTY.

Comment: Wait what? Thats a LOCAL php.ini

Comment: i have my host set as 127.0.0.1 and use an ssh tunnel to the remote server

Comment: @delboy1978uk
The server has a php.ini local on the machine. Where else should it be? Wait, what do you mean with "LOCAL"

Comment: The server is running on Windows? O_o I thought that was your dev laptop ini

Comment: @delboy1978uk
Yes, but that's not my fault. This is what I got. There is no way back. The project is too big by now. ^^"

Comment: can you ping or telnet the port of the remote server ok?

Comment: I can ping the server, but I can not telnet it.

Comment: @delboy1978uk
Okay, the problem is solved! Thank You!
Port 9000 was blocked by another firewall I did not not was existing on my PC. I found a free port that works now!

So to everyone out there who wants to enable Remote-xDebugging and thinks the configuration should be correct:
The firewall is probably the reason why it is not working. It might block the port for Debugging.

Comment: glad you got it sorted amigo!